# OpenVPN connected but cannot browse

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

i have setup openVPN on AWS using the AWS marketplace AMI. I am on a MAC , i am able to connect to the VPN but after connecting I cannot browse anything.

I tried to Ping `8.8.8.8`  this also stops as soon as the VPN connects. After connecting i am only able to access the VPN server from the browser.

Please suggest what could be the reason.

Comment: Yes , i want all my internet traffic to go via the VPN tunnel. Currently there is some issue with the gateway .. how do i resolve this ?

Comment: You will most likely have to add more information about your configuration for anyone to help you.

Comment: I actually did not do any manual configuration on AWS, i just installed via the AMI given , SSH to AWS , then accept the defaults. Setup default password for OpenVPN , then logged in from the UI by typing IP in Browser. Downloaded the config file from UI and connected.